# Text in a table disappears before wrapping

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

Windows Vista Home Premium with Microsoft Office 2010.

I have a table in Microsoft Word where the row size is not specified, but the columns are fixed.  When I type text that should wrap, it instead continues, invisibly, beyond the end of the row and then wraps 4 or 5 characters later.  So the table looks like this:

```
|this is text in the 1st cell|This is the 2nd cell which |But this cell doesn't |
|                            |has wrapped appropriately, |where it should.      |
```

The word "wrap" is missing after the word "doesn't" in the 3rd column. If I insert spaces at the beginning of the cell, I can watch the word "wrap" appear on the next line, while "doesn't" begins to disappear.  It's like the table thinks the column is a few characters longer than it is so it wraps too late, but can't show those characters that are beyond the end of the column.

Comment: Are you actually seeing the right border of the table? If you click in that right-most cell at look at paragraph format, what is the right indent?

Comment: Fantastic, Scott.  Thank you.  I was only looking at table properties.  Never occurred to me to check paragraph properties.  How it got to a negative number (-.36") I'll never know.  But now after setting that to 0, it's working correctly!  Thank you!!

Answer (score 8):

Click in that right-most cell
(or any cell that is having word-wrap problems)
and look at paragraph format. 
The right indent may have gotten set to a negative number.

Answer (score 1):

Steps:

- Select the table.
- Right click to show the popup menu.
- Click on the 'Table Properties'.
- Select the 'Row' tab.
- On the 'Specify Height' check box, input 0cm.
- On the 'Row Height is' select 'At least'.
- Then click 'OK'.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and discovered that a table had been embedded inside the cell of the main table. I copied the text, deleted the embedded table, and then pasted the text into cell. Fixed the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).